# window jumps back to the top on window resizing

Tags: menu, window, css-position, fixed

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            let menu = document.querySelector('.menubox');
            let menuTopBorder = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset;
            if (pageYOffset <= 40) {
            menu.classList.remove('fixed');
        } else if (pageYOffset >= menuTopBorder && !menu.classList.contains('fixed')) {
            menu.classList.add('fixed');
        }
        });
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .headerbox {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background: blue;
        }
        .menubox {
            width: 100%;
            background: yellow;
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .menubox.fixed {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        }
        
        /* deccoration */
        .text1,
        .text2,
        .menubox {
            font-size: 60px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .text1 {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
            background: green;
        }
        
        .text2 {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
            background: orange;
        }
```

```html
<section class="headerbox">
        <nav class="menubox">menu</nav>
    </section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 1</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 2</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 3</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 4</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 5</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 6</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 7</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 8</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 9</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 10</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 11</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 12</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 13</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 14</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 15</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 16</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 17</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 18</section>
    <section class="text1">Some Text 19</section>
    <section class="text2">Some Text 20</section>
```

When window width is being shrunk below 768px. Window jumps back to the top. I think it's because of fixed menu but i don't know how to fix it. I want window to stay on the same place when resizing below 768px.

When I shrink window below 768px, it jumps back to the top.I want window to stay on the same place when resizing below 768px.

I don't know why but this bug doesn't occur in stackoverflow code editor but it does appear when you run this code in file on your pc.

this is what it looks like.
[Window jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Z6x.gif)